# Freeze after closing lid. Suspend with pm-suspend works fine: Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T460s

Tags: 14.04, gnome, suspend, power-management, thinkpad

When I call `pm-suspend` from a terminal, it works fine. But when I close the lid (on battery, which should suspend the system) and reopen it, the system freezes and the CPU spins a lot. By the way, I'm using GNOME installed from the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package.

Any idea where should I start to debug?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. "sudo pm-suspend" works fine but when closing the lid or selecting "power->suspend" the system freezes at resume. This is the behavior:
Ubuntu login screens appears, mouse can be moved. However, the system is frozen: mouse clicks do not work, keyboard entries do not work, the clock is frozen at the time of suspension. "/var/log/pm-suspend.log" shows all success, no failures/errors.

My system is the following:
Ubuntu 14.04 latest update, Kernel 3.13.0-88-generic, Lenovo Thinkpad T450, Graphics card: Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]).